# What unit is font measured in

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, fonts

Within Unity we get to set "font size" to direct the size of a given text.

However nowhere does it seem to state what unit "font" is measured in within Unity.

All it says in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Font.html) is:

> Font Size:   The size of the font, based on the sizes set in any word processor.

however "any word processor" doesn't say alot...

Is it in:

- Points (pt)
- Pixels (px)
- Ems (em)
- Percent (%)
- Something else?

On glyphs it states:

> Adjusting the font size effectively changes how many pixels
>    are used for each glyph in this generated texture.

Which would make me think that font is also in pixels, but doesn't actually confirm it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does actually fontSize mean in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592712/what-does-actually-fontsize-mean-in-unity)